# Assign jQuery value to PHP variable inside ajax sussess

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "text",
    url:url,
    data:myKeyVals,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
var variable = result['value'];
<?php $phpvar = ?> variable <?php ;?>
}
```

How can I assign script variable to PHP variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "text",
    url:url,
    data:myKeyVals,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
    var variable = result['value'];
    document.cookie = "myAjaxResult=" + variable ;
   }
});
```

then in your php you can do this

```
$phpVar =  $_COOKIE['myAjaxResult'];
echo $phpVar;
```

I don't try my script above, so let me know if there is any error

Comment: i tried above script, i getting error document.cookie is not defined

Comment: hhmm , can i see your script ? the ajax part

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

> success: function(result){

With following line

> success: function(result){ console.log(result);

open your console and share the result what are you getting there. Then we might be able to parse it in correct way.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do will not work because the HTML (including the javascript) executes last and becomes static on your page after PHP is done. That means that you can not interact dynamically with PHP or have PHP triggered again on the current page using javascript because PHP is done rendering the page. This does not work:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "text",
    url:url,
    data: myKeyVals,
    dataType: 'json ',
    success: function(result){
        var variable = result.value;
        <?php $phpvar = ?> variable <?php ;?>
    }
});
</script>
<p>My variable is now <?php echo $phpvar ?></p>
```

What does work is:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "text",
    url:url,
    data:myKeyVals,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        // Put the variable into place using javascript
        $('#new-variable').text(result.value);
    }
});
</script>
<p>My variable is now <span id="new-variable">old<?span></p>
```

In the above instance, the word `old` will be replaced with the returned value from the code run on the `url` from your ajax. If you want want the PHP to retain the value going forward AND display it also on the current page, then you must change the PHP in your `url` to assign a session or a cookie:

**url (page from your ajax):**

```
<?php
# make sure you put session_start(); at the very top of all root/top-level pages
session_start();
# ...whatever your script is doing to get you $result['value'] goes here...
# Assign the value to session before output
$_SESSION['phpvar'] = $result['value'];
# Now output back to json for ajax
die(json_encode($result));
```

**back on your current page:**

```
<?php
# At the top of the page
session_start();
# Get our value if already set
$phpvar = (!empty($_SESSION['phpvar']))? $_SESSION['phpvar'] : false;
# Continue with page script...
?>
<!-- continue with html -->

<?php if(empty($phpvar)): ?>
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "text",
    url:url,
    data:myKeyVals,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        // Put the variable into place using javascript
        $('#new-variable').text(result.value);
    }
});
</script>
<?php endif ?>
<p>My variable is now <span id="new-variable"><?php echo $phpvar ?><?span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't need to store value in a php variable because you already have the value on your page inside a Javascript variable you can use it.